# Can this button send post data to php

Tags: css, button

I have the following piece of code give me a beautiful button that I want to use in a form.

```
"<div class='lbk'><a href='' class='btn_lft'>&nbsp Left</a></div>";
```

[image: Left Button]

On pressing the button I want to send some post data back to the page which is where I am totally stumped and can't figure how I can do it with this button.

It would be very simple to send it using a  basically a simple submit button. But then I won't get the arrow button that looks so neat.

Please can someone help me figure this out if it is possible. I do not wish to use Ajax etc. 
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use button type submit and overwrite the default appearance;

```
"<div class='lbk'><button type='submit' class='btn_lft'>Left</button></div>";
```

css:

```
button[type=submit].btn-left {
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none; 
    -webkit-appearance:none; 
    border: none;
    /* And some other css */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hm11o3oh/10/

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested. Did you by any chance mean `.btn_lft > input[type=submit] {` instead of `.lbk > input[type=submit] `. I have tried both and they both seem to remove my button. with .lbk, the whole div becomes the button and with .btn_lft, the button is replaced by the default button in html. Besides the post data is also not being sent when i wrap the `"<div class='lbk'><input type='submit' value='Left' class='btn_lft'/></div>";` in a form. Please say if I am missing something here or misinterpreted your reply. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer, because it's not: appearance: button, but appearance: none... my bad... check out the fiddle i've added

Comment: I think there is a confusion here. I am not using an image as a button rather using css to create one. The `<div class = 'lbk'` is there just to help position the css button which is itself created by the 'btn_lft' class.

Comment: ok, the principle is still the same... you can style the input type='submit' anyway you like... i'll edit my post again

Comment: I have tried this once again without luck. i.e. to say that once I make the changes the button changes to the default one and gets displaced to the top of the enclosing div. I am adding a fiddle which displays the button with the enclosing div. I request you to make changes to that and show me how this could be achieved. Thanks.[link]https://jsfiddle.net/ajoo/hm11o3oh/

Comment: I have modified the fiddle exactly as you suggested. Here is the latest link [link]https://jsfiddle.net/ajoo/hm11o3oh/3/. The triangular portion of the button disappears. Rest is all fine. I just don't know what I am doing wrong or missing. Kindly have a look and suggest. Thanks.

Comment: input type=submit is a little tricky I see, you can also use a button, as long as the type=submit. Check out the fiddle in my updated answer.

Comment: Yes while it retains the shape, it has killed the button press action due to the addition of `border: none; margin:none;`. Removing them distorts the button. Is it possible to still achieve the button press action while retaining the shape?

Comment: Do you mean the blue outline that usually appears on buttons? Then just remove "outline:none"... and you might want to add "cursor:pointer"

Comment: Hi, Well yes that fixes the blue border that appears on clicking. However I was asking about a change of color OR a button depression (seems like a button is pressed) effect that shows in buttons when they are pressed. I would also like to ask if the changes suggested by you are cross browser compliant. Thank you so much.

Comment: Check out the updated jsfiddle, adding the psuedo class ":active" allows you to add styling to the button while it is pressed. In the fiddle I gave it a black background and whit text, but you can do whatever you like. And yes, it should work on all browsers.